# Vue: update paths to static assets

Tags: vue.js, build, vuejs2, url-rewriting

I have Vue v2 SPA. This is standard application as it can be. Let it be `hello-world` from [the documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html). Let's make it and build:

```sh
vue create hello-world
cd hello-world
yarn install
yarn build
```

But I got a requirement: the application must be embedded (by URL rewriting, not deployed) into another site:

- Before the requirement: `https://site1.come/`
- After the requirement: `https://site2.come/path-toapp/` <- reverse proxy here rewrites the url `site1.com`

But application's build contains absolute paths for all assets:

```
$ cat dist/index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
...
<title>hello-world</title>
<link href=/css/app.fb0c6e1c.css rel=preload as=style>
<link href=/js/app.042151d6.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=/js/chunk-vendors.f0b6743d.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=/css/app.fb0c6e1c.css rel=stylesheet>
....
```

It breaks third-party site's rewrites. Resource `app.fb0c6e1c.css` will be got from:

```
https://site2.come/css/app.fb0c6e1c.css
```

Instead of:

```
https://site2.come/path-toapp/css/app.fb0c6e1c.css
```

How can I solve the problem? I didn't find any relevant configuration in vue's documentation.

Of course I have a solution. I can rewrite URL's in CI's script with bash:

```sh
sed -i "s/\(src\|href\)=\//\1=/g" dist/index.html
```

But the solution above is a hack and cannot be supported by web developers. Because of this I'm looking for more significant (webpack-based for example) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `vue.config.js` file in your project root, and set the [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) option:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/path-toapp/'
}
```